# How to Edit Data in Web App Flask and SQL server?

Tags: python, sql-server, flask

I created a web app Flask. I use **pyodbc** for connect to **SQL SERVER** database. I display **Tbl_product** with **@app.route('/product')**. **tbl_product** is a table with 4 columns: **P_ID**, **title**, **count**, **price**. I want to click on **Edit** of each row in *product page* and go to *Edit page* with values of title,count and price same row as default.Then I want to edit this information and return to *product page*.

my **app.py** is:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for, request, redirect, flash
import pyodbc

app = Flask(__name__)

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=TABRIZIYAN;'
                  'Database=market_DB;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

@app.route('/product')
def product():
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      resultValue=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Tbl_product")
      #if resultValue > 0:
      productDetails= cursor.fetchall()
      cursor.close()
      return render_template('product.html', productDetails=productDetails)

@app.route('/edit', methods=['GET','POST'])
  def update():
      if request.method =='POST':
      #fetch form data
         productDetails= request.form
         P_ID=productDetails['P_ID']
         title= productDetails['title']
         count=productDetails['count']
         price= productDetails['price']
         cursor = conn.cursor()
         cursor.execute("UPDATE Tbl_product SET title=?, count=?, price=? WHERE P_ID=?", 
                        (title,count,price,P_ID))
         conn.commit()
         cursor.close()
         return redirect('/product')
         return (render_template('edit.html'))
```

my **product.html** is:

```
<table bolder= 1px>
    <tr>
            <td> ID </td>
            <td> Title </td>
            <td> Count </td>
            <td> Price </td>
            <td> Action </td>
    </tr>
{% for product in productDetails %}
<tr>
    <td> {{product[0]}} </td>
    <td> {{product[1]}} </td>
    <td> {{product[2]}} </td>
    <td> {{product[3]}} </td>
    <td> <a href='/edit/{{product[0]}}'>Edit</a></td>

</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

my **edit.html** is:

```
<form method="Post" action="">
<h1> Edit product </h1>
    ID<br>
    <input type="text" name="P_ID"><br>
    Title<br>
    <input type="text" name="title"><br>
    Count<br>
    <input type="text" name="count"><br>
    Price<br>
    <input type="text" name="price"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How I do it?

Comment: Can you please share the resolution? I am stuck with similar issue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is:

`app.py` changed as below :

```
@app.route('/product')
def product():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Tbl_product")
    productDetails= cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('product.html', 
                        productDetails=productDetails)

@app.route('/edit/<string:P_ID>', methods= 
['GET','POST'])
def update(P_ID):
    if request.method=='GET':
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        productDetails1=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Tbl_product WHERE P_ID=?", 
        (P_ID))
        productDetails1= cursor.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        return (render_template("edit.html", productDetails1=productDetails1))


    if request.method =='POST':
        #fetch form data
        productDetails= request.form
        #P_ID=productDetails['P_ID']
        title= productDetails['title']
        count=productDetails['count']
        price= productDetails['price']
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("UPDATE Tbl_product SET title=?, count=?, price=?, active=? 
        WHERE P_ID=?",(title,count,price,active,P_ID))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        flash("Data Updated Successfully")
        return redirect('/product')
```

`edit.html` changed as below :

```
 <form method="Post" action="">
 <h1> Edit Product Page </h1>
   {% for product in productDetails1 %}
    <input type="hidden" name="P_ID" value={{product[0]}}" ><br>
    Title:<br>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{product[1]}}"><br>
    Count:<br>
    <input type="text" name="count" value="{{product[2]}}"><br>
    Price:<br>
    <input type="text" name="price" value="{{product[3]}}" ><br><br>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit">

 </form>
```